# Generating and displaying PDF with Syncfusion in React and ASP.NET Core Web API including responsive image annotations

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core-webapi, syncfusion

I'm working on a project where I have one or more images, and I want to be able to open a different form when clicking on specific areas defined by coordinates on these images. After filling out the form, I intend to collect the form data from the backend and generate a PDF file using Syncfusion. My goal is to then display this PDF within my React application.

However, I've encountered an issue when making the image responsive using the width property, as it seems to distort the coordinates I've defined. How can I tackle this challenge and correctly manage coordinates on a responsive image?

Furthermore, once I've generated and saved the PDF, how can I display it within my React application? When I use return file to send the PDF, how can I process and present the content of the generated PDF file within a React component?

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or insights from anyone experienced in working with these aspects. Thank you!

```
function CmrForm() {
  const [selectedIdentifier, setSelectedIdentifier] = useState(null);
  const handleClick = (event) => {
    const identifier = event.target.getAttribute("data-identifier");
    setSelectedIdentifier(identifier);
    console.log("Identifier of the clicked area:", identifier);
  };

  const formLayout = {
    xlg: 6,
    xl: 9,
    lg: 9,
    md: 6,
    sm: 8,
    xs: 12,
  };

  return (
    <div className="padding-10">
      <div style={{ maxWidth: "65%", position: "relative" }}>
        <img
          src={cmr}
          style={{
            width: "100%",
            height: "auto", 
          }}
          useMap="#form"
        />

        <map onClick={handleClick}  name="form">
          <area shape="rect" coords="1025,10,1158,52" data-identifier="1" />
          <area shape="rect" coords="85,56,619,202" data-identifier="2" />
          <area shape="rect" coords="624,56,1163,202" data-identifier="3" />
          <area shape="rect" coords="86,204,621,352" data-identifier="4" />
          <area shape="rect" coords="621,204,1160,352" data-identifier="5" />
          <area shape="rect" coords="87,358,622,453" data-identifier="6" />
          <area shape="rect" coords="626,358,1161,453" data-identifier="7" />
          <area shape="rect" coords="86,458,624,551" data-identifier="8" />
          <area shape="rect" coords="85,555,623,653" data-identifier="9" />
          <area shape="rect" coords="624,455,1160,653" data-identifier="10" />
        </map>
      </div>
      <Col {...formLayout}>
        {selectedIdentifier && <Form1 identifier={selectedIdentifier} />}
      </Col>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CmrForm;
```

ASP.NET Core Web API method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("showCmr/{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ShowCmr(int id)
    {
        var item =  _repo.GetDocCmr(id);

        if (item != null)
        {
            var pdfUtil = new CmrPdf();
            var x = pdfUtil.RenderPdf(item, _repoUser.GetUserClientCache(User.Identity!.Name));
            return File(x, MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);
        }

        return CreateActionResult(CustomResponseDto<NoContentDto>.Fail(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, new ApiErrorModel { Error = XmlLangHtmlExtender.L("NotFoundException") }, -1));
    }
```

When I make a request from Postman, it returns a file to me, but I'm unable to handle it in the React part.

Answer (score 0):

We've created a sample for you to see how a PDF can be displayed using a PDF Viewer. Here's a simple example to show you how it works:

React Sample: You can find an example of how this works in a React application by following this link: [React Sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-c8n53x?file=index.js,index.html,index.css).

Web Service Sample: You can also check out a sample of a web service by clicking here: [Web Service Sample](https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/Return_application-pdf-1446651858.zip).

Steps to View the Generated PDF in PDF Viewer:

1. Start by running the web service sample.
2. After that, run the React sample.
3. Click on the "Get PDF Data" button. This will send a request to the server.
4. On the server's side, the PDF will be generated, and it will be sent back as a response with the "application/pdf" content type.
5. The received "application/pdf" content type is then converted into a base64 string using the FileReader tool.
6. This converted base64 string is loaded into the PDF Viewer.

For more detailed information on how to work with form fields, annotations, and adding images to your PDFs, you can check out these links:

- [Working with Form Fields](https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/working-with-forms)
- [Working with Annotations](https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/working-with-annotations)
- [Working with Images](https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/working-with-images)